# Stream song via Spotify SDK without Spotify account on the users' side?

Tags: ios, api, ios7, stream, spotify

Is it possible to build an iOS app that streams from spotify in a way where it won't need the user to login to Spotify? In a way where only our application is registred.

It is just not clear after scanning through the SDK / API section.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I didn't work with the Spotify SDK

It should be possible. I suppose you can hardcode the login info in the code directly, and have the app login to spotify with the same user account every time (the one hardcoded in the app).

On the other hand, I don't see a good reason why you would want all the users of your app to connect as the same user to Spotify. But that is your decision :).

Also, I think you should also check the Spotify terms and conditions before you do that. Not sure if that's an issue or not.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, this sounds as a weird workaround. Furthermore, I think the same user can't function across 1000 devices at the same time. :D I don't want the users to sign in anywhere, but to listen to some famous audio track.